# Lip-reading software

Tags: computer-vision

I am looking for a [lip-reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lip_reading) program (aka. speechreading program). My main priority is to have a transcription as accurate as possible, so links to benchmarks are welcome to support accuracy claim. I'm mainly looking for a solution working with English speakers. If possible, free, open source and Windows 7.